# trying to understand missing values

Tags: trend

When I add a trend smooth line to a multiple time series plot I keep getting missing values

```
Removed 2 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path)
```

although the data looks fine to me,

```
        date    cost     inc      month
1 2019-07-11   50.00    0.00 2019-07-01
2 2019-07-11   50.00    0.00 2019-07-01
3 2019-07-15 1743.48    0.00 2019-07-01
4 2019-07-26 1000.00    0.00 2019-07-01
5 2019-07-01    0.00 2000.00 2019-07-01
6 2019-09-01    0.00 2500.00 2019-09-01
7 2019-10-01    0.00 1973.96 2019-10-01
```

I "gather" the variables with,

```
df <- a %>% select(date, cost, inc) %>% gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -date)
```

and make an area plot with,

```
> ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
+     geom_area(aes(color = variable, fill = variable), 
+               alpha = 0.5, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
+     scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
+     scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

but when I add the trend smooth line I keep getting, "Removed 2 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path)" (as well as a bunch of other singularity and reciprocal condition errors) no matter what data I delete or change.

```
> p + stat_smooth(color = "#FC4E07", fill = "#FC4E07",method = "loess")
```

[graph with trend smooth line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRWjq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just forgot to define "p" first as the multiple time series plot.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
    geom_area(aes(color = variable, fill = variable), 
              alpha = 0.5, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

values are okay, and graph looks like this:

[multiple times series area plot with smooth trend line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXhln.png)